# sh Script to find files(only xml) in a directory, execute a python script (.py) on every file found, source the changed files into a target directory

Tags: python, linux, shell, loops, foreach

I have a python script (as a .py file) that modifies xml file headers. I want to find all the files with extension .xml in a directory, copy them to a different directory and run the python script on all the *.xml files that are copied. I would like to source all the changes files through the python script into a different directory.

Currently I am at this step:
`find . -type f -name ".xml" -exec cp {} tempdir \;`

I am new to shell and I do not know how to execute the python program on each file that's sourced to `tempdir` and output to a new `targetdir`

my python command to execute looks something like this: `python "xmlchange.py" -i "tempdir" -t "targetdir"`

I am thinking of a `foreach` or a `for` loop whichever is appropriate in this context.
Any inputs appreciated. TIA!

Comment: Can your `xmlchange.py` script accept multiple filenames on the cmd line?  .i.e. `./xmlchange.py -t "tmpdir" -i f1.xml f2.xml f3.xml`? Good luck.

Comment: I would rather give a input directory because there will be 1000s of Xml files to process. Thank you !

Comment: OK, makes sense. Does your xmlchange.py contain a loop designed to process all the files it finds in the current directory? I think you need to include a super-small sub-set of your `.py` file that shows how it gets a filename, and then creates the output (and where it puts it). So you don't need any processing of the file, just a `print "inside file " $file` (the `.py` equivalent). Normally, I would have a shell script that does `cd /path/to/data ; for f in *.dat ; do /path/to/xmlchange.py "$f" > /path/to/outputDir/"$f" ; done` and leave it at that. Try to clarify your Q for python readers.

Comment: @kat : What does _hat's sourced to_ mean, i.e. what does it mean to _source a file to a directory_?

Comment: @kat : According to your problem description, your `xmlchange.py` accepts as input parameter not an individual file, but a whole directory. So what's the point to loop over the files in the calling shell process? I think your problem boils down to _how can I loop **within Python** over all XML files in a given directory_.

Comment: Sorry if the description is confusing. The py script accepts only files. So, in my shell script - I have to iterate over each file that's in the ```tempdir``` , send it to py script and the changed xml file has to be passed to a new ```targetdir```